# How to make EBS volume to be available with zero downtime and attach to EC2 instance when ebs volume crashes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, amazon-ebs, aws-application-load-balancer

I have one r5.xlarge windows ec2 instance which is attached to 6TB EBS volume and the backup for EBS is taken every week.
Now I want a better solution with zero downtime.

1. if ec2 instance fails I want new ec2 instance to be to created and it should be attached to EBS volume automatically.
2. if EBS volume crashes I want backup snapshot to be available and gets attached to ec2 instance with zero downtime and volume content available immediately.

Is there a way to implement solution for this and how?

Comment: There is no such thing as zero downtime if you plan to use two single points of failure (1 EC2 instance + 1 EBS volume)

Comment: @Maurice recently my EBS volume got corrupted and it took 12-18 hrs to be available. Is there any better way to do so that EBS volume is available even if it crashes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to improve the availability of the large drive, I would recommend FSx. It's not so trivial - you need to set up Active Directory, and your EC2 needs to join AD - but once you have all these components (and there is additional cost as well) - FSx provides significantly higher availability than EBS assuming you're using a multi-AZ setup.
More information [here](https://aws.amazon.com/fsx/windows/)

Note that load balancer tags are irrelevant to your question - although to address your first situation you probably need load balancer balancing two EC2 instances

Comment: EFS is incompatible with Windows instances, that won't work. FSx could do the trick, maybe you meant that?

Comment: Of course! I meant FSx for Windows; and the link should be https://aws.amazon.com/fsx/windows/ So sorry for confusion :)

Comment: I updated the answer and you get my upvote ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You should try and use Elastic BeanStalk, this will handle the autoscaling on its own. You just have to configure the settings while creating it.
This should be the nearest solution that you need, as explained by Marcin above there is no zero downtime for 2 single point of failures. So Elastic BeanStalk seems to be the best solution for you.

Updated:

So in this case what you can do is add a load balance and add auto scaling, so that the first point of your questions is taken care and if the ec2 instance goes down through autoscaling a new instance will be create and in the shell script you can add commands to map to the EBS.
And for EBS, there isn't much you can do, you can take regular backups and if the EBS fails then replace it with the latest backup or snapshot, also check the below link:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-restoring-volume.html

Comment: I use this server to store file and run automation scripts and recently ebs volume got corrupted and it took 12-18 hrs to be available. Is there any better way to do so that EBS volume is available even if it crashes? Even if use elastic beanstalk does this ebs problem occur?

Comment: If you want to use it only for storing files then try to use EFS or S3.

Comment: I have many automation scripts and application running for which I need EBS and this is a windows instance that can't attach EFS . And this ec2 instance is accessed by mostly 30-40 users through remote desktop.

Comment: It should be explained by Maurice:-)